# Manipulate Function Variables in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is this possible?

Take for example this code

```
class LuaCamera
{
    public:
        LuaCamera(lua_State* L);
        static bool defaultControls;
        bool FPSCam;

        int lookAt(lua_State* L);
        int getRotation(lua_State* L);
        int setRotation(lua_State* L);
        // ...

        virtual ~LuaCamera();
        static const char className[];
        static const Luna<LuaCamera>::RegType Register[];
    protected:
    private:
};
```

As you can see, I'm using Lua, so I want to document the Lua-usage. 
Instead of getting `int setRotation(lua_State* L)` in the Doxygen output, I want to see `void setRotation(int x, int y, int z)`. Likewise, I want the class to be named `Camera` in the output instead of `LuaCamera`.

I realize I could rename the class and create unused functions in order to do this, but my program has an extensive amount of Lua functions and that would be a poor approach.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question fully. I understand that you want to document the "expanded" form of the methods and remove any Lua reference from the names?

Comment: Yeah. I need to document the lua-usage in the C++ code

Comment: Wouldn't it be clearer to wrap that Lua usage, and then comment the wrapper? Unless you can't modify the code...

Comment: Maybe you can use an [input filter](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_input_filter) to convert your files. You can use them to hook your own program that converts the source code before it is fed into doxygen.

Comment: Thanks Karsten, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided just to make a very simple script that does the task I need.

For anyone who might be looking for a similar solution, here is the source to the python file:

```
import os;

path = "include/";
output = "doxygen/src/";
modOutput = False;
srcFiles = os.listdir(path);

def writeFile(fileName, cont):
    f = open(fileName, "w");
    f.write(cont);
    f.close();

def readFile(fileName):
    cont = open(fileName, "r");
    return cont;

def readFileLines(fileName):
    return readFile(fileName).readlines();

#   creates the original files without the \mod option.
def outputNormalSrc():
    for srcFile in srcFiles:
        fileLines = readFileLines(path + srcFile);
        newFile = "";

        # We want everything in the original src files except for \mod lines.
        for line in fileLines:
            if line.find("\mod") >= 0:
                line = line[ : line.find("\mod")] + "\n";

            newFile += line;

        writeFile(output + srcFile, newFile);

#   creates the modded files for Lua doxygen output.
def outputModdedSrc():
    for srcFile in srcFiles:
        fileLines = readFileLines(path + srcFile);
        newFile = "";

        foundClass = "";
        for line in fileLines:
            if foundClass == "" and line.find("class") >= 0:
                foundClass = line[line.find("class")+6 : -1];
                break;
        if foundClass == "":
            print "WARNING: couldn't find class in src file " + srcFile + ". Skipping.";
            continue;

        newFile = "class " + foundClass + "\n{\n";

        getLines = False;
        writeBeforeClass = False;
        inMod = False;
        whiteSpaces = "";
        for line in fileLines:
            # We want everything in the block quote.
            #   If the block quote is for the class, put it before the class definition.
            if line.find("/**") >= 0:
                getLines = True;
                if line.find("class") >= 0:
                    writeBeforeClass = "";

            # Store the \mod function name.
            if line.find("\mod") >= 0 and getLines:
                inMod = line[line.find("\mod")+5 : -1];
                line = line[ : line.find("\mod")] + "\n";

            # Here we start storing the necessary lines we need for the output.
            if getLines or line.find("public:") >= 0 or line.find("private:") >= 0 or line.find("protected:") >= 0 or line.find("}") >= 0:
                if writeBeforeClass != False:
                    writeBeforeClass += line;
                else:
                    newFile += line;

            # The end of the block quote.
            if line.find("*/") >= 0 and getLines:
                getLines = False;

                # If we are writing the block quote before the class.
                if writeBeforeClass != False:
                    newFile = writeBeforeClass + newFile;
                    writeBeforeClass = False;

                # Add our modded function in place of the normal function.
                if inMod != False:
                    newFile += whiteSpaces + inMod + ";\n";
                    inMod = False;

            # Used to append whitespaces the beginning of modded functions
            #   based on the previous line's whitespaces.
            whiteSpaces = "";
            for i in range(len(line)):
                if line[i].isspace() == False:
                    break;
                whiteSpaces += line[i];

        # Create the files.
        writeFile(output + srcFile, newFile);

def main():
    # Choice: Create the original output without the \mod command,
    #           or with the \mod command to overwrite function definitions.
    if modOutput:
        outputModdedSrc();
    else:
        outputNormalSrc();

main();
```